# cannot stop/remove/destroy datetimpicker function (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

i have condition that need datetimepicker and stop datetimepicker function, my code:

```
$('.berdasarkan').on('change', function(){
     thisval = $(this).val();
     if(thisval == 'klien'){
         $('input[name="search"]').datetimepicker('remove');
         console.log('1');
     }else if(thisval == 'tanggal'){
         $('input[name="search"]').datetimepicker({
             format:'DD-MM-YYYY'
         });
         console.log('2');
     }else if(thisval == ''){
        console.log('3');
     }
});
```

but datetimepicker still running when i choose first condition, is my code wrong ?

[SOLVED]

I am using this code :

```
$('input[name="search"]').data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
```

Comment: Try using `.datetimepicker('destroy')` instead of "remove". Check out docs: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove datetimepicker, you just need to remove the class "berdasarkan" which you are using.

Comment: `.berdasarkan`  is different element with `$('input[name="search"]')` ,